# Getting answers to your question

Tags: discussion

A few days ago I asked a question and fairly quickly I got a response but it seemed like a scripted response and the solution was already something I knew about and had tried. Since then I have gotten nothing except a question on the database version. Now I understand that people are busy but to be completely ignored this long is frustrating.

Now I've volunteered on technical support forums before on topics that I am good at and the users on the forums don't just stop replying after the first answer even if it doesn't work. That makes me wonder if that is what is going on here. Do the experts here just offer one answer and then stop?

I'll say that what I'm not good at is Sharepoint server which is why I am trying to install it however I can't even get it to work which is why I came here. Can anyone help at all or is my case useless? Please don't take this wrong way but I came here for help and I am not getting any.

Comment: Hello townsbg, Welcome to SE Community. Regarding your question, I think Moe & Mike have provided the full answers in response to your question. But since I am the person who answered your question. I would first to apologize to you and point out that our main objective here is to help everyone as much as possible based on our modest experience, if we can help we will :)

Comment: By the way, As @Moe said (I fully appreciate his awesome answer), I tried to provide an answer within 9 minutes since the question was asked.I also replied to you in comments and when I can not help I stopped.

Also, as Mike said (I fully appreciate his clear answer) this is **a community-driven knowledge base** We aren't paid consultants. Meanwhile, we are trying to help everyone as much as possible.
I hope it is clear now :). Please don't hesitate to inform us if you have further questions. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 9):

First of all, no one should demand or possibly even expect an eventual solution-bringer to their question. Every answer is written by someone doing it by their free will, so even a great community can't guarantee complete "customer" satisfaction.

If it's been a few days since the question was asked with a little input from others, I would expect it to become never answered on next to any volunteer-based support area.

---

Generally questions, which

- are well formed;
- are specific;
- show research effort by e.g. providing links to materials you have gone through to confirm they don't apply to your case, or further excluding information; and
- don't require significant post-editing/detailing,

tend to become answered more likely. I'm sorry to bring it up, but your question didn't match to any of these.

An exact search by a search-engine for the error brings thousands of results. This is a yellow flag for a too inaccurate error description. I would imagine one can answer to the question exactly only if she has faced the exact issue earlier and happens to see your question. And, after all, SharePoint provides extremely detailed logs which should record any errors and give further details about the issue.

Also I'd like to point that the question in its current form is still a bit unclear for me, as you say

> I just installed MOSS 2007 with the latest service pack on Windows 2008 R2 SP 1.

and the actual question-line is

> Do I need to install Windows 2008?

To learn more about asking a question, you should read the related [Help-documentation about asking](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

---

To get to your questions on this meta question, you are pointing on something which is true, but also explainable.

The community is not run by scripted answer-bots that look up the Try-my-luck-google-result, so don't worry about that! It's actually very likely, that many of the 30+ people who opened your question tried to look up for an answer without hitting any. Each view is the opposite of ignorance, so you are not a victim of such.

When a user who attempts to help you doesn't get back to you, it's more or less the sign of "I'm sorry, I don't think I can help you any further". Now this could be said aloud, but the comment area is not exactly meant for that (see [When should I comment?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)).

---

To wash my hands, I got to say that the many users of SP.SE or any SE who provide answers (or even comments) are extremely willing to help. There just are and will be questions which we can't provide sufficient answers.

What kind of saddens me, is that if a community member like you thinks

> I came here for help and I am not getting any.

although you have received a personally written answer attempting to **help** you **within 9 minutes** since the question was asked.

Answer (score 5):

You just witnessed what many people in this community go through. A question that isn't answered to your likeness. Questions that have been answered are less likely to receive a second answer. I get it, but please understand that this is a community-driven knowledge base. We aren't paid consultants. Some questions can get answered faster than others, and SP.SE takes a back seat to their jobs, hobbies, family life, etc.

Don't take this the wrong way, but if you want immediate support, I'd suggest looking into a Software Services firm or call Microsoft. They'd be happy to give you the attention you are looking for.